# Override Case - Close button(workflow action)

Tags: acumatica

I want to add an error message that pops up when a case is being closed when not all tasks have been completed.

I usually can override the method like this

```
   public delegate IEnumerable CloseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Close(PXAdapter adapter, CloseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
```

The problem is this is a workflow action.
Is it possible to add my code to this workflow?
if it's possible to disable the button using my code it will also work.
I don't know what my options are any insight will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would fully override the action by copying the entire action signature into your graph extension

```
public PXAction<MainDac> close;
[PXButton] // <=
[PXUIField] // <= Make sure this all is EXACTLY the same
public IEnumerable Close(PXAdapter adapter)
{
   if (your check is true)
   { // throw your popup or exception here
   }
   return Base.Close.Press(adapter); // This invokes the base action
}
```